# Keras CNN TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'JpegImageFile'

Tags: keras, tensorflow, numpy

I try to set up a multiclass CNN with Keras which relies on `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory`.

Unfortunately I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 578, in get
    inputs = self.queue.get(block=True).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 401, in get_index
    return _SHARED_SEQUENCES[uid][i]
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image.py", line 1296, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image.py", line 1773, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image.py", line 423, in img_to_array
    x = np.asarray(img, dtype=backend.floatx())
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 501, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'JpegImageFile'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn.py", line 145, in <module>
    Cnn()
  File "cnn.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.train_model()
  File "cnn.py", line 69, in train_model
    validation_steps=50)
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1415, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 230, in fit_generator
    workers=0)
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1469, in evaluate_generator
    verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 327, in evaluate_generator
    generator_output = next(output_generator)
  File "/home/torben/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 584, in get
    six.raise_from(StopIteration(e), e)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
StopIteration: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'JpegImageFile'
```

This is my Keras code:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('../image-classifier-files/train',
                                                    target_size=(constants.IMG_SIZE, constants.IMG_SIZE),
                                                    batch_size=32)
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('../image-classifier-files/val',
                                                        target_size=(constants.IMG_SIZE, constants.IMG_SIZE),
                                                        batch_size=32)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(constants.IMG_SIZE, constants.IMG_SIZE, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))

model.add(layers.Dense(self.simterm_count, activation='sigmoid'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              steps_per_epoch=100,
                              epochs=30,
                              verbose=2,
                              validation_data=validation_generator,
                              validation_steps=50)
```

Comment: What version of Keras are you using? Given that your code is more or less that of the documentation, the latest version of Keras should work.

Comment: I'm using Keras 2.2.2 :/

Comment: Are your samples in the required tree-structure in the folders? From [the docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class): "directory: Path to the target directory. It should contain one subdirectory per class."

Comment: Can you check if any of your image is corrupted/broken or not?

Comment: @n1k31t4 yes, the three structure is correct. It already worked with less images.

Comment: @AnkitSeth I'm already deleting images which are not `imghdr.what('/tmp/bass') == 'jpeg'` or without a filesize. Maybe there is a better way to do this? :-)

Comment: Maybe file an issue on the Keras GitHub. There may be a known cause. I definitely cannot see one from your code. The only related error message I Found was due to people opening files using `PIL`, which leaves the format in an undesired form. As you are using Keras' own API, I can't believe that to be the case for you.

Comment: Alright, much appreciate your quick reply. Going to file the issue now.

Comment: btw found an existing issue here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10668

I will check tomorrow if there is a better method to detect broken jpegs with Python!